# ERROR Error: Error trying to diff 'false'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this function in TS:

```
getClientContact(clientid: string) {
        if (this.client&& this.client.length > 0) {
        const [filteredClientId] = this.client.filter(pt => pt.client_id === clientid);
        if (typeof filteredClientId !== 'undefined' && clientid === filteredClientId.client_id) {
        return filteredClientId.contactNo;
    }
  }
}
getClientAdd(clientid: string) {
        if (this.client&& this.client.length > 0) {
        const [filteredClientadd] = this.client.filter(pt => pt.client_id === clientid);
        if (typeof filteredClientadd !== 'undefined' && clientid === filteredClientadd.client_id) {
        return filteredClientadd.address;
    }
  }
}

onSelect(clientid) {
            this.selectedClient = null;
            for (let i = 0; i < this.client.length; i++) {
                if (this.client[i].client_id === clientid) {
                    this.selectedClient = this.client[i];
                }

            }
        }
```

I call it in html like this code:

```
  <fieldset>
      <legend>Client Data</legend>
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <select (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)" [(ngModel)]="selectedClient.client_id" formControlName="client_id" id="client_id"
          materialize="material_select" [materializeSelectOptions]="client">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Nome:</option>
          <option *ngFor="let item of client" [value]="item.client_id">{{item.clientName}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="input-field col s12">
       Phone:
        <br>
        <span>{{getClientContact(selectedClient.client_id)}}</span>
        <br>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        Address:
        <br>
        <span>{{getClientAdd(selectedClient.client_id)}}</span>
        <br>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
```

In this code I get this error `ERROR Error: Error trying to diff 'false'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed` when `client` is empty.

Please, can you ask me any idea, how can I modify the code to not display this error? It's very important for me.

Comment: Instead of creating your client as empty or undefined you can make your client equal to an empty array `client = []`

Comment: Either declare your client as an empty array as `client = [];` or add an additional check in the template for null or undefined values of client with `*ngIf` before iterating.